# need the number of days in a month, datedif()?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am new to this. Is it possible to use datedif() or any other function so that one enclosed the name of the month and it returns the number of days that month has?

Comment: For ***Frebruary*** you also need the year.

Comment: What are your language settings??

Comment: What version are you using?  and in what country do you reside?

Answer (score 3):

Use this formula that returns the day number of the last day of the month of that current year:

```
=DAY(EOMONTH("1 " & A1,0))
```

[image]